# How to fix code PHP DOM HTML Parse - Loop

Tags: php, html, parsing

## I started to play building a PHP HTML Parser,

and I have some trouble:

### The HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class="list">
<div class="b">
 <div class="c">
  <a href="http://link.com">
   <div class="d">Category</div>
   <div class="e">
    <img src="https://link.com/img.png">
   </div>
   <h1>TITLE</h1>
   <div class="f">paragraph 1</div>
   <div class="g">paragraph 2</div>
   <div class="h">
    <div class="i">
     <div class="j">Quot</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="b">
 <div class="c">
  <a href="http://link2.com">
   <div class="d">Category2</div>
   <div class="e">
    <img src="https://link2.com/img.png">
   </div>
   <h1>TITLE 2</h1>
   <div class="f">paragraph 12</div>
   <div class="g">paragraph 22</div>
   <div class="h">
    <div class="i">
     <div class="j">Quot 2</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

### My PHP Code:

```
$classname = "list";
$xPath = new DomXPath($dom);
$find = $xPath->query("//* 
[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
$get = $find->item(0);
$link = $get->getElementsByTagName('a');
$data = array();

foreach ($link as $val)
{ $data[] = array(
'link' => $link->item($no)
->getAttribute('href'),

 );

$no++; 
}
```

### I want the results like this:

-http://link.com
  -category
  -http://link.com/img.png
  -paragraph 1
  -paragraph 2
  -quot
  -http://link2.com
  -category2
  -http://link2.com/img.png
  -paragraph 12
  -paragraph 22
  -quot2

Comment: Can you provide more information like errors messages you get or what goes wront etc.?

Comment: Your code specifically finds links, yet you seem to be looking for paragraphs as well. Please elaborate.

Comment: Forgive me for asking, what is it you are attempting to do? If you are just trying to manipulate dom elements, may I suggest jQuery? https://jquery.com. Its pretty powerful and will allow you to search and manipulate the dom you could even add some flair with fading really easily. By the way, css classnames can be re-used. So instead of a,b,c,d you could name them based on their location.

Comment: Nevermind about the css class names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you could do it using jQuery and Mustache js a templating tool.

https://jsfiddle.net/mcroteau/zyouxfq4/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Mustache.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var row = `
    <div class="content-row">
        <div class="link">
            <a href="{{link}}" title="{{category}}">{{link}}</a>
        </div>
        <h1>{{category}}</h1>
        <img src="{{image}}" style="border:solid 1px #ddd; height:20px; width:20px;"/><br/>
        <p>{{paragraphOne}}</p>
        <p>{{paragraphTwo}}</p>
        <p>{{quote}}</p>
    </div>
    <hr/>`;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var $mainContentDiv = $(".list")
    var $mainList = $(".b");

    $mainList.each(function(){
        var data = {}
        var content = $(this).find(".c")
        var $content = $(content)

        var link = getLink($content)
        var category = getCategory($content)
        var image = getImage($content)
        var paragraphOne = getParagraph($content, 'f')
        var paragraphTwo = getParagraph($content, 'g')
        var quote = getQuote($content)

        data["link"] = link
        data["category"] = category
        data["image"] = image
        data["paragraphOne"] = paragraphOne
        data["paragraphTwo"] = paragraphTwo
        data["quote"] = quote

        var html = Mustache.to_html(row, data);
        $('#links-container').append(html);

    })

    function getQuote($content){
        return $content.find(".j").html()
    }

    function getParagraph($content, className){
        return $content.find("." + className).html()
    }

    function getImage($content){
        return $content.find("e").find("img").attr("src")
    }

    function getCategory($content){
        var category = $content.find(".d")
        return $(category).html()
    }

    function getLink($content){
        return $content.find("a").attr("href")
    }


    $mainContentDiv.remove()

})
</script>
```

Is this something like you wanted to achieve?